# Can I add a attribute and a restriction to a xsd type inline?

Tags: schema, xsd, xsd-validation

I need to imply a restriction and an attribute on a type. I know it can be done this way

```
<xs:simpleType name="Name">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="MyCustomeName">
      <xs:simpleContent>
             <xs:extension base="mc:Name">
                    <xs:attribute name="MyTypeOfName" fixed="MCN"/>
             </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Is there a way to do all in one line "inline"

I can add the restriction inline but then I cannot add the attribute as in

```
<xs:simpleType name="MyCustomName">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
        <xs:attribute name="MyTypeOfName" fixed="MCN"/>          --> This gives an error
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The reason why I want to do this... is we expose the XSD to a 3rd party and they have issues with the inheritance of the types hence I want to do all inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to merge a restriction and extension into one block in XML schema. The solution that you show with `<simpleType>` and `<complexType>` IMHO is the way to do so.

If you don't want to define the `<complexType>` you can define directly the `<element>`, but it's basically the same that you're doing without the possibility to reuse your `<complexType>`:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Name">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="15"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="MyCustomeName">  
    <xs:complexType>  
        <xs:simpleContent>  
            <xs:extension base="Name">  
                    <xs:attribute name="MyTypeOfName" fixed="MCN"/>
            </xs:extension>  
        </xs:simpleContent>  
    </xs:complexType>  
</xs:element>
```

Hope this help,

Comment: Thanks albciff. All my findings indicated the exact same.